# Swift require that two generics are of the same type

Tags: generics, swift

In the Swift programming language I see an example

```
func anyCommonElements <T, U where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.GeneratorType.Element: Equatable, T.GeneratorType.Element == U.GeneratorType.Element> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {
    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

It appears that `T.GeneratorType.Element == U.GeneratorType.Element` means that the elements generated when the sequences are decomposed share the same underlying type.  So I can do

```
anyCommonElements("123", "1234")
anyCommonElements([1, 2, 3], [1])
```

but not

```
anyCommonElements("123", [1, 2])
```

But `T: Sequence, U: Sequence` means that the parameters T and U have to be sequences, such as a String or an Array.

What is the proper way to write a function that takes two parameters T and U which are required to be the same type using the where clause?  Omitting the `T: Sequence, U: Sequence` requirement results in the error "GeneratorType is not a member of type T"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @conner noted but you would never specify it that way as there is only one type.  This is better:

```
func functionName<T> (lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both of your parameters to be the same type, you can just use the same generic for both of them. Something like:

```
func functionName <T, T> (lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Oh duh, I way over thought that one